# WCF Rest 400 bad request image size

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I have searched all over and tried all solutions but nothing seem to work for me. 
I get the bad 400 request when uploading an image bigger then 64k.
It was working then suddenly it stopped working. No code change or change to config file as well.
What else could affect the config file settings ?
Here is my config file

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" name="EzFindWCFService.EZFindWebService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="EzFindWCFService.EZFindWebServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="EzFindWCFService.EZFindWebService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>



      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EzFindWCFService.EZFindWebServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <!--<enableWebScript />-->
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">          
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" allowCookies="false"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: share your web service `web.config` file

Answer (score 0):

In system.serviceModel/services/service you set the binding to "webHttpBinding" but you don't define a bindingConfiguration.
The problem is that you didn't set up a webHttpBinding in system.serviceModel/bindings. You set up a basicHttpBinding and set its *name* to webHttpBinding! So in fact this complete binding is not used, because your service-element looks for a default (because you didn't define a bindingConfiguration) webHttpBinding and not for a basicHttpBinding with name webHttpBinding! That is the reason why your upload fails for files bigger than 64k. Because this would exceed the default quota of 64k.
I hope that you understand me :) mixing default binding names is quite error-prone ;)

**Update:**

This system.serviceModel-Section should work:

```
<services>
  <service name="EzFindWCFService.EZFindWebService" 
           behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" >
    <endpoint address="" 
              binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ConfigWebHttp"
              behaviorConfiguration="EzFindWCFService.EZFindWebServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
              contract="EzFindWCFService.EZFindWebService" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EzFindWCFService.EZFindWebServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <!--<enableWebScript />-->
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ConfigWebHttp"
             openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I left out some default settings (e.g. binding/security) to make the config a bit more slim.
One more thing: I'd be careful with settings all those quotas to Int32.MaxValue. It may be ok for testing, but keep in mind to set those values down, when you go into production.

Comment: Thanks for seeing this. So all I have to do is change the <basicHttpBinding> to <webHttpBinding> ? then all should work ?

Comment: Please amend my config file where you see the wrong info. All your help is much appreciated.